# Sort Element - Can it work with/as a variable from GET to UPDATE

Tags: update, filters, sort, variable, get

Situation. We are tidying up some flows so they use less GET's.
We have one that gets a single highest value of the last 6 months.
Previously we had a filter (for its requirements) then a descending loop.
Then outside of the loop we had an assign the last item to a variable.
Debugging, it gets the correct value but gets {null} in the assignment (because its outside of the loop).
Colleague suggested using a sort but we couldnt find a use for it in this scenario.

Thought? Happy to share more info if unclear :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include screenshots of the flow elements and clarify "we couldn't find a use for it".  How were you trying to use the sort?  Please [edit] your post.